# Fancier verbatim?

Tags: code-snippets

I was going through `enumitem`'s documentation ([here](https://ctan.gust.org.pl/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)) and I really like how it includes text in angle brackets in its code snippets (e.g. `label=`⟨*commands*⟩ on p. 4). I took a look at the `.tex` file ([here](https://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.tex)), but I can't figure out how the author made it happen using `|label=<commands>|`. I want to ask which package is responsible for handling this.

Comment: Using `|...|` as a shorthand for verbatim code is a feature of the class. Try `\documentclass{ltxguide}
\begin{document}
|label=<commands>|
\end{document}
`